# Prove a set given by an inequality is open

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I am not quite sure how I'm supposed to prove some things in Apostol's volume 2 problems. In particular:

> 2. In each of the following cases, let $S$ be the set of all points $(x, y)$ in the plane satisfying the given inequalities. Make a sketch showing the set $S$ and explain, **by a geometric argument**, whether or not $S$ is open. Indicate the boundary of $S$ on your sketch.

The first case is an open ball of radius $1$, which I could prove is open by employing the triangle inequality. But the second case, $3x^2 + 2y^2 < 6$, as well as the next ones, were a mystery to me. What does Apostol mean by "geometric argument", precisely?

Comment: Recall from pre-calculus the equation of an ellipse.